# How to set excel sheet name in BIRT API?

Tags: java, excel, birt

When I use birt api to export excel, the excel's sheet name is default set to `Sheet0`. Is there a way to custom sheet name in birt API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Property Editor - Report" in the tab "General" you can enter a "Title".

This value will be taken to name the sheet when exporting to excel.

[image: ExcelSheetName]

Answer (score 2):

I had a report with two table and page break after the first one so each table made their own sheet. after selecting each table go to the script and in the "on create" script, code this:
**this.name = "Sheet Name";**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can add Dynamic/Static Worksheet name.

Select **Table**, click in **Script** (**onPrepare**), use below line of code.

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().setProperty("title", "Sheetname1");
```

Sheet name can also be passed through request parameter (**workSheetName**) using below line of code.

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().setProperty("title", params["workSheetName"].value);
```

[image]